# Why have these gconftool-2 commands stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome-terminal

In ubuntu 14.04 running these `gconftool-2` commands at a command prompt would change the profile settings for gnome terminal.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color --type string "#393939"
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_colors --type bool false
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color --type string "#fff"
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_type --type string "transparent"
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_darkness --type float 0.95
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/scrollback_unlimited --type bool true
```

If I use the command `gconftool-2 --get <some setting>` , `gconftool-2` prints the corresponding value, also the values are being written into the file (as XML)

```
/home/velour/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/%gconf.xml
```

but the values seem to be ignored by gnome terminal.
how can gnome terminal profiles be configured from the command line in 16.04?.

Comment: [Same as 15.10, perhaps?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/731774/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-profile-preferences-using-dconf-or-gsettings) `gconftool` for Gnome 2, `gsettings` for Gnome 3.

Comment: @Gilles thanks. I suspected the developers changed the system, I just needed someone knowledgeable to point me in the right direction!

Comment: Expect it to happen every time the gnome devs decide that fixing bugs is boring so a complete rewrite is needed.  Going on past history, that'll be at least once every few years.  Yay, we beat windows - we have multiple inadequately documented and inscrutable registries, not just one.